# Sweet alert isn't displaying error/succesfull alert while first time writing wrong password

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display error/successful alert in the login panel. But sweet alert isn't displaying error/successful alert while first time writing wrong/correct password. I must to write one more time wrong password to showing sweet alert. I didn't understand why it is like this. I tried to inspect codes with breakpoint. In first time its going to `Login.cshtml` and although `ViewBag.status` is false its not going to `if (ViewBag.status==false)`. Can someone help me?

Controller;

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(TBLUSER t)
    {
        var values = db.TBLUSER.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MAIL == t.MAIL && x.PASS == t.PASS);
        bool status;
        if (values != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(values.MAIL, true);
            status= true;
            ViewBag.status = status;
            Thread.Sleep(2500);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Panel");
        }
        else
        {
            status = false;
            ViewBag.status = status;
            Thread.Sleep(2500);
            return View();
        }
    }
```

View;

```
 <div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-login100">
        <div class="wrap-login100 p-t-50 p-b-90">
            <form class="login100-form validate-form flex-sb flex-w" method="post">
                <span class="login100-form-title p-b-51">
                    LOGIN
                </span>
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-16" data-validate="Mail is required.">
                    <input class="input100" type="text" name="MAIL" placeholder="Mail">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-16" data-validate="Password is required.">
                    <input class="input100" type="password" name="SIFRE" placeholder="Password">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-sb-m w-full p-t-3 p-b-24">
                    <div class="contact100-form-checkbox">
                        <input class="input-checkbox100" id="ckb1" type="checkbox" name="remember-me">
                        <label class="label-checkbox100" for="ckb1">
                            Remember me
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a href="#" class="txt1">
                            Forgot pass?
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container-login100-form-btn m-t-17">
                    <button class="login100-form-btn" id="btn1">
                        Login
                    </button>

                    @if (ViewBag.status == false)
                    {
                        <script>
                            $('#btn1').click(function () {
                                swal("Error", "Wrong password, please try again.", "error");
                            });
                        </script>
                    }

                    @if (ViewBag.status == true)
                    {
                        <script>
                            $('#btn1').click(function () {
                                swal("Information", "Successfully u have logged in.", "success");
                            });
                        </script>
                    }
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:170px">
                    You dont have an acc? <a href="#" class="txt1">Create</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```